# Any bounded linear operator maps pre-compact sets to pre-compact sets

Tags: functional-analysis

> **Proposition 1)** Prove that any bounded linear operator maps pre-compact sets to pre-compact sets.

**My proof:**

Consider $X$ and $Y$ to be two normed spaces and $A$ is an arbitrary bounded linear operator, $A:X\to Y.$

$A\in L(X,Y)$, space of linear bounded operators. $\sup_{A\in(L(X,Y))}=C$, so this implies that $\forall A\in L(X,Y),\:\:\exists c\implies\|A\|\leq c.$

> **Arzela-Ascoli Theorem**:  any subset M is pre-compact if and only if the subset is equicontinuous.

Consider the compact subset $M\subset X.$ s
Since $A$ is bounded and linear it is continuous, so:
$\exists \delta>0$ and $\|x_1-x_2\|<\delta$. $\exists \epsilon>c\delta$

$|A(x_1)-A(x_2)|\leq c\|x_1-x_2\|<c\delta<\epsilon\:\:\:\forall A\in L(X,Y)$

Since the subset $A(M)$ is equicontinuous, it is pre-compact.

**Observation**: I think that the proposition **1)** is equivalent to: Prove that any continuous linear operator maps pre-compact sets to pre-compact sets. Since $A$ is bounded and linear hence it is continuous. It could be used the fact that continuous functions preserve compactness hence proving the proposition desired.

**Questions**:

What do you think of the proof? What do you think of the observation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This makes no sense at all, sorry. The A-A theorem applies to sets of functions on a space satisfying certain conditions; if $X$ and $Y$ are Banach spaces it doesn't make any sense to say a subset of $X$ or $Y$ is equicontinuous.

Comment: There’s seems to be a misunderstanding here. The Arzelà Ascoli theorem (and the concept of equicontinuity) applies to collections of functions; $A(M)$ is not a collection of functions, it is the image of $M$ under $A$ which is a subset of the normed vector space $Y$. Also the statement that continuous functions map compact sets to compact sets is a bit stronger because it doesn’t require the assumption of linearity, so I’m not sure your observation really follows from this.

Comment: @User8128 Sorry but A is a collection of functions, since $A\in L(X,Y)$, that is why I am using Arzela-Ascoli.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Which conditions are you referring to the application of Arzela-Ascoli theorem? What if X and Y are Banach spaces? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @PedroGomes Yes, $A\in L(X,Y)$. So $A$ is a function. And the inequality above shows that $\{A\}$ iis equicontinuous. So what? $\{A\}$ is obviously compact in any relevant topology because any finite set is compact. Compactness of $\{A\}$ has nothing  to do with the question. Nothing whatever. (In particular $M$ above and $A(M)$ above are not collections of functions...)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I mean since ${A}$ is equicontinous so it is $M\subset Y$ which implies that M is pre-compact according to Arzela-Ascoli theorem.

Comment: @PedroGomes Huh??? I have no idea what "since $A$ is equicontinuous so it is $M\subset Y$" even _means_! **Look:** Saying $M\subset Y$ is equicontinuous is sheer total nonsense, because $M$ is not a set of functions! (Also: You don't need to show that $M\subset Y$ is precompact -  you're _given_ that $M$ is precompact, and you have to show that $A(M)$ is precompact.)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Sorry I meant $A(M)$ instead of $M$. What do you think then?

Comment: @PedroGomes What I think about that is that you're simply not reading what people are writing. Saying $A(M)$ is equicontinuous is nonsense. Gibberish. Completely and totally ridiculous. Because $A(M)$ **is not a set of functions.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** It seems there's some confusion about the meaning of "precompact". For the record, in my terminology a subset of a topological space is precompact if it has compact closure.

This is true in much greater generality: If $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces and $f:X\to Y$ is continuous then the image of any precompact subset of $X$ is a precompact subset of $Y$. On reflection maybe we need to assume that $Y$ is Hausdorff:

Say $E\subset X$ is precompact. Then $\overline E$ is compact, so $f(\overline E)$ is compact. Since $Y$ is Hausdorff this implies that $f(\overline E)$ is closed.

So $f(E)\subset f(\overline E)$ implies that $\overline{f(E)}\subset f(\overline E)$, and hence $\overline{f(E)}$ is compact, being a closed subset of a compact set.

Comment: That is the argument for relatively compact sets. To speak of precompactness, one needs a uniform space. The image of a precompact (or totally bounded) set under continuous maps need not be precompact, e.g. $X = (0,1)$ (with the Euclidean metric) is precompact, but for $f \colon X \to \mathbb{R}$, $f(x) = 1/x$ the image is not precompact ($\mathbb{R}$ also with the Euclidean metric). The image of a precompact set under a uniformly continuous map is again precompact.

Comment: Well, at least in the terminology that I learnt. I just found out that "precompact" is also used to mean "relatively compact". Hrrmph.

Comment: Hrrmph indeed. Not that terminology is supposed to  make sense, but "relatively compact" makes little sense to me. I've always taken "precompact" to mean "compact closure". First few hits on google agree...

Comment: @DanielFischer I can't tell from your comment what your favored definition of precompact _is_...

Comment: A uniform space is precompact if its completion is compact. Then we have the useful theorem that a uniform space is precompact if and only if it is totally bounded.